# Continuing a while loop after error in R

Tags: json, r, loops, while-loop, skip

I am trying to use a while loop to download a bunch of JSON files.

They are numbered from 255 to 1. However, some of them are missing (for example, 238.json does not exist).

```
scheduleurl <- "http://blah.blahblah.com/schedulejsonfile="
i <- 255
while ( i > 0) {

    last = paste0(as.character(i), ".json")
    path = "/Users/User/Desktop/Temp"
    fullpath = paste0(path, last)
    ithscheduleurl <- paste0(scheduleurl, as.character(i))
    download.file(ithscheduleurl, fullpath)
    i <- i - 1
    }
```

I basically want to write my while loop such that if it encounters a nonexisting file (as it will when i = 238), it basically continues to 237 instead of stopping.

I tried the tryCatch() function this way, but it didn't work (keeps trying the same URL) :

```
while ( i > 0) {
    possibleError <- tryCatch({
    last = paste0(as.character(i), ".json")
    path = "/Users/dlopez/Desktop/Temp"
    fullpath = paste0(path, last)
    ithscheduleurl <- paste0(scheduleurl, as.character(i))
    download.file(ithscheduleurl, fullpath)
    i <- i - 1}
    , error=function(e) e) 

    if(inherits(possibleError, "error")) {
            next
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `tryCatch({...}, silent = TRUE)`?

Comment: Why `while` over simple `for`??

Comment: Is there a significant advantage of one over the other? (I'm a total novice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[url.exists](http://127.0.0.1:18954/library/RCurl/html/url.exists.html) from the RCurl package should do the trick.

```
library(RCurl)

while ( i > 0) {

last = paste0(as.character(i), ".json")
path = "/Users/User/Desktop/Temp"
fullpath = paste0(path, last)
ithscheduleurl <- paste0(scheduleurl, as.character(i))
if (url.exists(ithscheduleurl)) {
download.file(ithscheduleurl, fullpath)
}
i <- i - 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tchotchke! Indeed, I just tried:

if(url.exists("url in question")) { do work}

I'll just use url.exists before trying download.file. Thanks for the advice!